# horizontally align link and heading in center of wrapper

Tags: html, css

I am need of some help. I am currently working on a project for my course of Webdesign.

I am stuck on this and this only.
I want to get icons horizontally centered with the headings below (img) [press me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JRUc.png)
my html of that part:

```
<!-- Three pillars of the company -->
 <section id="pillars" class="clearfix">
      <h2 class="structural">Three pillars</h2>
      <div class="wrapper">
           <section class="clearfix" id="border">
                <a href="services.html" id="cloudicon_large">Cloud</a>
                <h3>Cloud Computing</h3>
                     <p>
                          I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and  edit me. I’m a great place for you to tell a story and let your users know a little more about you.
                     </p>
           </section>
           <section class="clearfix" id="border">
                <a href="services.html" id="desktop_large">Desktop</a>
                <h3>Security</h3>
                     <p>
                          I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and  edit me. I’m a great place for you to tell a story and let your users know a little more about you.
                     </p>
           </section>
           <section class="clearfix">
                <a href="services.html" id="phone_large">Phone</a>
                <h3>Mobility</h3>
                     <p>
                          I'm a paragraph. Click here to add your own text and  edit me. I’m a great place for you to tell a story and let your users know a little more about you.
                     </p>
           </section>
      </div>
 </section>
```

my css:

```
/* CSS for Pillars section */

#pillars .wrapper > section {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 1rem;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
    text-align: center;
}

#pillars a {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#pillars .wrapper > section h3 {
    font: normal normal normal 17px/1.4em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

#pillars .wrapper > section p {
    font: normal normal normal 12px/1.4em 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

/* CSS for icons in pillars section */

#cloudicon_large {
    display: block; /* only block level elements can have width / height */
    height: 10rem;
    white-space: nowrap; /* single line of text */
    text-indent: 100%; /* push text outside */
    overflow: hidden;  /* hide text outside */
    background-image: url(../img/cloud_folder_large.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#desktop_large {
    display: block; /* only block level elements can have width / height */
    height: 10rem;
    white-space: nowrap; /* single line of text */
    text-indent: 100%; /* push text outside */
    overflow: hidden;  /* hide text outside */
    background-image: url(../img/desktop_small.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#phone_large {
    display: block; /* only block level elements can have width / height */
    height: 10rem;
    white-space: nowrap; /* single line of text */
    text-indent: 100%; /* push text outside */
    overflow: hidden;  /* hide text outside */
    background-image: url(../img/phone_large.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

As you can see I made links and replaced the text with images (css image replacement).

There is a requirements: 
**Fluid/Flexible design so no relative/absolute positioning**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these images are background-images in elements that span the whole width, you can simply add `background-position: 50%` to all three of them to move them into the middle.

Here#s a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdQeqp

Comment: woops. Now it doesn't work anymore. I need the heading and the image replaced centered link like this: http://prntscr.com/b3rem7

Comment: BTW: You are using `id="border"` on *two* elements, but IDs are supposed to be unique/ only used once in a page.

Answer (score 0):

add `background-position:center;` to the css for each element you want the `background-image` to be centered.

Comment: it doesn't work. I need the heading and the image replaced centered link like this: prntscr.com/b3rem7

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#cloudicon_large {
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 10rem;
    white-space: nowrap; /* single line of text */
    text-indent: 100%; /* push text outside */
    overflow: hidden;  /* hide text outside */
    background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/koud5th8/

Comment: Can you use javascript?